# css menu maker won't work mobile

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, menu, navigation

I want to use [this menu](http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/flat-jquery-responsive-menu) 
for my website. It work well on desktop (even the mobile version) but on my Iphone 4s the mobile version won't work.

I only add this to the css of the menu.

```
nav{
    &#cssmenu{
        font-family:$font-principale !important;
        #menu-line {
          background: $couleur-principale;
        }
    }
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-color: $couleur-principale !important;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: $couleur-principale !important;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  background: $couleur-blanc !important;
  color: $couleur-gris-fonce !important;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a:first-child {
    border-top:1px solid $couleur-gris-pale;
}   
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  border-bottom: 1px solid $couleur-gris-fonce !important;
  border-right: 1px solid $couleur-gris-fonce !important;
}
```

What is the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all this

```
nav{
    &#cssmenu{
        font-family:$font-principale !important;
        #menu-line {
          background: $couleur-principale;
        }
    }
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-color: $couleur-principale !important;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: $couleur-principale !important;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  background: $couleur-blanc !important;
  color: $couleur-gris-fonce !important;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a:first-child {
    border-top:1px solid $couleur-gris-pale;
}   
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  border-bottom: 1px solid $couleur-gris-fonce !important;
  border-right: 1px solid $couleur-gris-fonce !important;
}
```

and it's work.
I will add my css directly in the css menu marker css